# How to play video in a link from website using HTML5 in my python script?

Tags: python, html, video, wsgi

I have this python script code and I am using wsgi module in apache. The table has id and video_filename.

video_filename contains one filename in each row.  Each filename is a video filename. The video filename has extension .mp4.  For example:

ID      video_filename
........
4      video4.mp4
3      video3.mp4
2      video2.mp4
1      video1.mp4

The number of videos will increase every day automatically in my database table. This is already done in other script I already done.

Using this python script I show a table with ID a video filename.

```
import sqlite3
def application(environ, start_response):

 db = sqlite3.connect('/var/www/html/table.db')
 db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
 cursor = db.cursor()
 cursor.execute('''SELECT id, video_filename FROM table ORDER BY id DESC''')
 results = ['<table><th>id</th><th>video_filename</th>']
 for row in cursor:
  results.append('<tr>')
  results.append('<td>{0}</td>'.format(row['id']))
  results.append('<td>{0}</td>'.format(row['video_filename'])
  results.append('</tr>')
 db.close()
 results.append('</table>')

 headers = [
 ('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'),
 ('Content-Length', str(sum(len(line) for line in results)))
 ]

 start_response('200 OK', headers)

 return results
```

This code works.

What I want is only display a video when the user click in a specific video filename. I know I have to use HTML5 video controller tag. But I do not know how to do it.

The filename video are record in the database but also saved in /var/www/html/

for example:

/var/www/html/video1.mp4

Any help?

I would be great that when I click in the link display the specific video filename pop up. When I close the video then come back to the table id video_filename as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a javascript function that will load the video to the HTML, and it will be activated on click to the table cell the video name is in.

```
results.append('<td onClick="playVideo({0});">{0}</td>'.format(row['video_filename'])
```

In JS:

```
function playVideo(name) {
    var urlPrefix = window.location.href + '/var/www/html/',
          url = urlPrefix + name;
    alert(url);
    // load url to html video tag
}
```

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks for your code.  I will try this code.   One question: Is there any security issue with this javascript code? I mean someone could tamper data and modified /var/www/html for example /etc/passwd ?

Comment: He could easily do that even without JavaScript, straight through the browser (: . Moral - do not leave your sensitive urls without protection. You can require a password in the request parameters before returning the demanded resource.

Comment: results = ['<script type="text/javascript">.....</script>']    The javascript function should go inside results where are .... no?

Comment: It is a valid approach, but it is not the best you could do. If you do not have any other javascript on the page, you should create a new .js file, put your code inside of it. Then you should include that file in the html page that you use this html in.  
If you already have some javascript in another file, just add this to the file too.

Comment: I add a code <html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="video.js"><script></head><body><table>....   but does not do nothing.  Video.js has the javascript code. The other option    When I try in the same python script to add javascript function playVideo(name).... It says that global name var is not defined

Comment: Well, check in the browser what requests are made. I bet that the request for video.js returns 404 not found.  If this is true, you have to change the src attribute to point to the right directory where the video.js file is.